# Access Control List Keycloak Quarkus

Tags: keycloak, wildfly, quarkus

In Keycloak WildFly, access control could be done by adding **filters** in standalone.xml like below:

```
<filters>
     <expression-filter name="adminAccess" expression="path[/auth] -> ip-access-control(acl={'10.0.0.1 allow'})"/>
</filters>
```

How can I have the same logic in Keycloak Quarkus?
Note that I don't want to use proxy at this step.